# Angular 7 & Laravel

Tags: angular

I have face some problem while implementing ng2-pdf-viewer.

Ts file:

book-pdf-viewe.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';
import { fileUpload } from '../commonUrl'; import { BookService } from'../book.service';

@Component({  
      selector: 'app-book-pdf-viewe',   
      templateUrl: './book-pdf-viewe.component.html',  
      styleUrls: ['./book-pdf-viewe.component.css'] 
     })

export class BookPdfVieweComponent implements OnInit {

       urlofFile = fileUpload;   
       pdfSrc: string;

       constructor(
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
        public bookService:BookService,   ) {

        console.log(data.filename,data.book_id);
        this.bookService.getSpecificbook(data.book_id).subscribe( bookData => {
          console.log('first',bookData[0].file);
          this.pdfSrc = this.urlofFile+'uploads/books/'+bookData[0].file;
           console.log("2nd",this.pdfSrc ) 
         })   
        }

       ngOnInit() {

       } 
 }
```

**Problem:1**

Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8000/uploads/books/1548048467_sw.pdf' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

**Problem:2**

core.js:15714 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Worker': TypeError: Failed to fetch could not be cloned.
Error: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Worker': TypeError: Failed to fetch could not be cloned.

**N.B.** backend Laravel 5.7

cors.php

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods',' GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token , Authorization');
```

Comment: Use So policy to style code

Comment: Problem 1 : from my viewpoint the problem is on server side, that does not accept cross origin requests. 

So, the problem is not related to the component code your posted, but the book.service client code and may be the pdf renderer(server side)..... **Please post book.service code** . some settings in the pdf rendering server may be needed to enable cross origin requests (CORS). And be sure you have don't have any firewalls that locks some things.

Comment: Book.service.ts                                                                                                
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';import { Observable } from 'rxjs'; import { api } from './commonUrl';export class BookService {httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
    })};constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  getSpecificbook(data): Observable<Book[]> {
    return this.http.get<Book[]>(api + 'book/get_book/' + data, this.httpOptions);
  }}